# Delete and Update Database in PXDatabase

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to delete the rows in the DB on the processing page, but during `PXDatabase.Delete<>` and `PXDatabase.Update<>`, does not react in any way what is the problem?

```
using (IEnumerator<PXResult<MyTable>> enumerator = PXSelect<MyTable, Where<MyTable.inventoryID, Equal<Current<INItemSiteSummary.inventoryID>>, And<MyTable.siteID, Equal<Current<INItemSiteSummary.siteID>>>>>.SelectMultiBound(this, new object[] { itemsite }).GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                PXDatabase.Delete<MyTable>(new PXDataFieldRestrict[]
                    {
                        new PXDataFieldRestrict("InventoryID",itemsite.InventoryID),
                        new PXDataFieldRestrict("SiteID",itemsite.SiteID)
                    });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to commit your update and delete in cache to save during persist or hit the DB directly when called? Ideally you want to commit the change to cache and let it all complete during a persist.

Comment: @Brendan how to do it in processing page ? what option do you propose? because it `this.Caches[typeof(MyTable)].Delete(deleteLine);` `this.Caches[typeof(MyTable)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Delete);` `this.Caches[typeof(MyTable)].Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);` does not work

Comment: You need a view for it to persist. So after you add your view (pubic PXSelect<MyTable> MyTableView) you would use MyTableView.Delete(row). Then when you call persist the data will deleted